# Read SCSS variable in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

To target the art direction problem (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) I need to make use of the `<picture>` element in my markup. I have my images resized with paperclip into 4 different styles: lg, md, sm, xs.

I'm using bootstrap (SCSS) and have defined my breakpoints through variables:

```
$screen-xs: 425px;
$screen-sm: 768px;
$screen-md: 1000px;
$screen-lg: 1200px;
```

To use the `<picture>` element, I have to refer to this breakpoints in my ERB markup:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 425px)" srcset="<%= image.attachment(:xs) %>">
  <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="<%= image.attachment(:sm) %>">
  <source media="(max-width: 1000px)" srcset="<%= image.attachment(:md) %>">
  <source media="(max-width: 1200px)" srcset="<%= image.attachment(:lg) %>">
  <img src="<%= image.attachment(:md) %>" alt="<%= image.alt %>">
</picture>
```

Of course, I don't want to maintain breakpoints in two different places (and I'm going to extract this into a helper), so I was wondering if it's possible **to read the SCSS variable in a ruby method in rails?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to read SCSS variable in a ruby method, hovewer I'd like to propose a solution that doesn't require that.

You could define values in helper and use them in your stylesheets and HTML.

To embed ruby code into scss file, rename `*.scss` to `*.scss.erb`:

```
# hepler.rb
def screen_xs
  '425px'
end

def screen_sm 
  '768px'
end
...

# style.scss.erb:
$screen-xs: #{screen_xs};
$screen-sm: #{screen_sm};
...
```

Comment: I don't want to define variables in ruby and use it in ERB, I want it the other way around. Furthermore, this prevents the asset pipeline from minifying the CSS

Comment: @23tux Replying to 3 years old comment, but you can inject CSS3 variable in view and use it in SCSS.

```
# application.html.erb
<style>
:root {
  --screen-xs-size: screen_xs
}
</style>

# style.scss
$screen-xs: var(--screen-xs-size);

```